# Sorting a Firebase Query by timestamp seems to return 0 results [go programming language]

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

**Problem Overview:**
I'm querying a "Sessions" collection for sessions with a UserID == string, this works fine. But when I try and OrderBy("DateCreated", Desc) which is of type timestamp I get 0 results

**What I've tried:** 
I've checked the DB and the property I'm using which is called "DateCreated" and it's  a valid timestamp type. All sessions data is generated in go with random date ranges.

**Current Results:**
*returns 100 results* (correct)
firstSessionQuery := db.Collection("Sessions").Where("UserID", "==", uid).Documents(ctx)

*returns 0 results VS 100* (incorrect)
firstSessionQuery := db.Collection("Sessions").Where("UserID", "==", uid).OrderBy("DateCreated", firestore.Asc).Documents(ctx)

```
firstSessionQuery := db.Collection("Sessions").Where("UserID", "==", uid)
allDocs, err := firstSessionQuery.Documents(ctx).GetAll()

docsSorted := firstSessionQuery.OrderBy("DateCreated", firestore.Asc).Documents(ctx)
allDocsSorted, err := docsSorted.GetAll()
fmt.Printf("docs len: %v, docs sorted len: %v\n", len(allDocs), len(allDocsSorted))
```

the first %v returns 100, second %v returns 0

**Expected results:**
My expected results are 100 sessions sorted by date, either ascending or descending.

**Here are db screenshots:**
[here is the DateCreated prop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTxiq.png)

[Here is the UserID prop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwxk1.png)

[Terminal fmt printout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmoIQ.png)

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

That work for me in a similar context

```
db.collection("Sessions")
            .orderBy("DateCreated", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
```

Comment: Yes, this should be trivial so I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: I've OrderBy with a less complex type "number" and still getting 0 results, so there's either a major bug in the Go firebase library(not likely) or I'm missing something(more then likely).   

I've looked through the docs and can't see what I'm doing wrong:  
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/order-limit-data

Answer (score 0):

It was **user error**:

I was mapping the data to a custom **type Session struct{}** and one of the props was set to **int** when it should have been **string**, I wasn't catching the err.